# Being able to keep track of user's data after my app has been closed

Tags: ios, data-storage

I have created an app for the iPhone where I have two view controllers. Page 1 has a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`, and Page 2 has a `UIImagePickerController` that allows the user to update the image on Page 1 and a `UITextField` that allows the user to update the `UILabel`. The image view on Page 1 has a default image placed there, in case the user doesn't care to change it.

I won't post my code as it works fine as is.

My problem is that if a user chooses to change the image displayed on the first page, I would like to save their choice of image somewhere, so when the app is opened thereafter, their own  image of choice will be displayed, rather than the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to save the user's preference (an ivar of some sort). And upon relaunching your app, query the defaults to check for which preference has been selected and load the image based on that preference.